# How to get the spline formula in R?

Tags: r

The following code will plot points and a spline (obtained by the spline function):

```
x <- 1:7
y <- c(2,1,4,2,5,1,2)
# plot the points
plot(x, y)
# plot the spline
lines(spline(x, y, n = 100, method = "natural"), col = 2)
```

What I need is the function itself obtained by `spline(x, y, n = 100, method = "natural")` so I can get the value of `y` given any `x`. how can I do that?

I tried the code below but it doesn't work

```
f <- spline(x, y, n = 100, method = "natural")
f(7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?splinefun`, as referenced on the `?spline` help page.

```
f <- splinefun(x, y, method = "natural")
f(1)
#[1] 2
f(2)
#[1] 1
f(3.5)
#[1] 2.901923
```